# Derby Embedded Database using Authentication

Tags: java, derby

Apache Derby Embedded Database in default manner it doesn't need authentication. We can enable authentication in system level or database level. I made system level enabling using java code.

```
Properties p=System.getProperties();
p.put("derby.connection.requireAuthentication", "true");
```

Then I tried create the database using this connection URL.

```
jdbc:derby:derbysample;create=true;user=root;password=root
```

When i run this

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
```

It creates database folder also throw errors regarding authentication? How to create a database with credentials?

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection authentication
>   failure occurred.  Reason: Invalid authentication..   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.checkUserCredentials(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   derbytest.DerbyTest.createConnection(DerbyTest.java:56)   at
>   derbytest.DerbyTest.main(DerbyTest.java:39) Caused by: ERROR 08004:
>   Connection authentication failure occurred.  Reason: Invalid
>   authentication..  at
>   org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 15 more

Comment: There's extensive documentation about Derby security features, including a whole section on authentication: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/security/cseccsecure42374.html

Answer (score 3):

First specify the database URL that you are going to create with properties `create=true`

```
jdbc:derby:derbysample111;create=true
```

Then get Connection using `DriverManager`. It will create a database if it is not exist.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:derbysample111;create=true");
conn.setSchema("APP");
```

Then enable authentication in derby and set user and password. It will set database level authentication.

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(\n"
            + "    'derby.connection.requireAuthentication', 'true')");
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(\n"
            + "    'derby.authentication.provider', 'BUILTIN')");
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(\n"
            + "    'derby.user.root', '12345')");
s.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(\n"
            + "    'derby.database.propertiesOnly', 'true')");
```

It is only need to be set once. Then can access your database using this URL

```
jdbc:derby:derbysample111;create=true;user=root;password=12345
```